# Does BootstrapUI fully support original functionality of Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-ui

I am new to the bootstrap framework, but already I want to be able to use AngularJS rather than the provided jQuery that comes out of the bootstrap box.  The documentation for BootstrapUI seems easy enough, I can simply download the code from github and include it in my Django project.

What I am not so unclear on, and maybe I missed this in the documentation somewhere, but is this intended to fully replace the javascript components of bootstrap?  For example there are a lot of JS libraries that are being delivered via CDNs in the bootstrap examples that appear to make the site browser independent.  For example, in the jumbotron examples, I see the following code:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="' + {% static 'bootstrap/docs/assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js'%} + '"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/docs/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js' %}"></script>
```

With BootstrapUI is this something I take out or leave in?  Just what exact steps do I need to perform in order to use Angular instead of jQuery in a bootstrap powered site?  The documentation doesn't really go over this.  Please point me to the right place if I've missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI-Bootstrap basically contains a bunch of Bootstrap components where the original JavaScript/jQuery has been re-written and wrapped in AngularJS directives which can be easily dropped into your application.

As per the docs,

> This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS. **As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required**.

Comment: Okay.  I understood that.  But exactly how?  What directives for example replace the browser specific code like the ones I posted?  That is the missing link in my understanding

Comment: @Matt1776 -- I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but as I stated you don't need any of the scripts you've included in your code snippet. You simply add a script reference to UI-Bootstrap (via CDN, Bower, NPM, Yarn, etc...) and then inject 'ui.bootstrap' into your application.

Comment: So then if I understand you correctly, all the browser specific JS that bootstrap comes with is *automatically* implemented by that single line of code?  That is what was not obvious to me.  But if that's the case then holy shit that is amazing!

Comment: @Matt1776 -- I think you're missing the key point which is that you have to include the UI-Bootstrap library (.js) script in your application -- like you would with Bootstrap or jQuery. Then you can simply use all the directives in it by including 'ui.bootstrap' in your application.

Comment: Of course I understand that I have to make a reference to the js file for ui bootstrap, but the fine detail that I am unclear on is does this file include all the functionality as bootstrap and all the aforementioned script references or do i physically need to make explicit references using the new directives and if so what would they be?

Comment: Ben what the hell was I on about here? I have just been using bootstrap for about 6 months now and these comments seem insane to me now - I was definitely confused. You just drop in the bootstrap-ui library which replaces the bootstrapJS and you're good to go

Comment: @Matt1776 It's amazing how much knowledge changes in such a short period of time :)